# Laravel 5.4 orderBy on morphTo relation

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to order the results of a morphTo relation in Laravel 5.4. The below example does not work. Adding an orderBy method on other relations ( eg hasMany() ) does work.

```
class OrderLineItem extends Model
{
    public function eventtable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo()->orderBy('date');
    }
}
```

I have been able to order the result set after the query, by using sortBy on the collection. But would be good to order the results in the query. The date col is always available in the polymorphic related tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OrderLineItem extends Model
{
   public function eventtable()
   {
      return $this->morphTo()->orderBy('date','Desc');
      //or you can use 
     //return $this->morphTo()->latest('date');
   }
}
```